# clear() goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, g++

The output is an infinite loop of "cannot open the file". what did I do wrong? thanks in advance. (p.s I am trying to test the condition that it cannot open the file and continue processing by getting the next file name from the vector)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
ifstream input;
vector<string> files;
files.push_back("ifile");
files.push_back("ifile2");
vector<string>::const_iterator iter=files.begin();
while (iter!=files.end())
{   
    string s;
    input.open(iter->c_str());
    if (!input)
    {
        cerr<<"cannot open the file"<<endl;
        input.close();
        input.clear();
        continue;
    }
    while(input>>s)
        cout<<s<<' '<<ends;
    input.close();
    input.clear();
    cout<<endl;
    ++iter;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: clear is normally called on an open file after a badbit to continue processing the file. Try just taking it out? not sure what it is doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply enough, you're not incrementing the iterator in your error case.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!input)
{
    cerr<<"cannot open the file"<<endl;
    input.close();
    input.clear();
    ++iter;
    continue;
}
```

You need to increment your iterator here.

Comment: Or one could remove all the lines following `cerr`. The following input loop would simply be skipped anyway. - After all you are closing a file you couldn't open and it causes no harm.

Answer (score 1):

1. iter = files.begin()
2. begin loop
3. open fails
4. iter is not incremented
5. goto 2

A better way of writing this may be to use a `for (;;)` loop, with the iterator increment happening in the third clause, so that a `continue` does not bypass it.